# javax.jta.Transactional on CDI with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, cdi, jta, java-ee-7

As far as i have read here, this combination should work:

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public List<ServerGroupDto> getAll() {
    List<ServerGroup> result = getSession().createCriteria(ServerGroup.class).list();
    return result.stream().map((e) -> {
            ServerGroupDto retval = new ServerGroupDto();
            retval.setGroupName(e.getGroupName());
            retval.setRejectCallOnSessionLimit(Boolean.valueOf(e.getRjtCallForSessLimit()));
            retval.setRouteByWeight(Boolean.valueOf(e.getRouteByWeight()));
            return retval;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But Hibernate will complain: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction`.

Have I done something not ment to be done? Using Hibernate 4.3.11 & Wildfly 8.2.1. The above code is CDI ApplicationScoped.

Comment: do you have a producer for your entitymanager? are you using a JTA datasource? you shouldn't need Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED. @Transactional is just fine.

Comment: @TerrenceCurran correct, but question says nothing about `EntityManager` and JPA - it looks that Hibernate is used directly.

Comment: @G.Demecki oh right. I didn't notice that. Does transactional work with direct hibernate? I would think no.

Comment: @G.Demecki yes i am using Hibernate directly (need multi tenancy). I have a producer for Sessions.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  For example, the full stack trace, your full class, etc.  FWIW, I use Hibernate MultiTenancy w/ the entity manager interface without issue, but I also use DeltaSpike Data.

Comment: @JohnAment do you mean you are using JPA with multi tenancy?